# How to convert RxJS v4 application to RxJS v5 version

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am working on converting [this](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/examples/backpressure) application to support RxJS version 5. But I am not sure how to convert below code.

```
losslessClick.subscribe(function (checked) {
  if (checked) {
    mousemove.resume();
  } else {
    mousemove.pause();
  }
})
```

I tried suggestion from [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542) but did not work for me.

```
var pauser = new Subject();
var pausable = pauser.switchMap(paused => paused ? Observable.never() : mousemove);
pausable.subscription(x => console.log(x));
pauser.next(true);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
var losslessResults = document.getElementById('losslessResults');
var losslessToggle = document.getElementById('losslessToggle');

function logInput(text) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = text;
    losslessResults.appendChild(li);
}

var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    .map(function (e) {
        return 'clientX: ' + e.clientX + ', clientY: ' + e.clientY;
    });

// Lossless
var losslessClick = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(losslessToggle, 'click')
    .map(function (e) {
        return e.target.checked;
    })

var pauser = new Rx.Subject();
var pausable = pauser.switchMap(function (paused) {
    return paused ? mousemove : Rx.Observable.never();
});
pausable.subscribe(function (x) {
    return logInput(x);
});
pauser.next(true);
losslessClick.subscribe(pausable)
```

Working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnnk6hv3/).